# The question is about Meta Description and General Description

Tags: meta

Is there any reason why the General description and the Meta Description need different text? We are asking this especially with a view as to whether Google penalises if duplicated.

We are struggling to think of different things to say in both sections.

Thank you

Lisa

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't recommend using exactly the same text. Always try to avoid duplicate texts anywhere on the web...however, you can use the same targeted keywords in meta description and general description. Meta description is for search engine, that's how a link to your site will look like in SERP, so maybe you want to describe your product differently for those who can see you link in SERP and those who browsing your site.

Answer (score 0):

Lisa Venn, if you have talk of about Magento `product description and meta description` then you need  understand what is different between products description and meta description.

Google is taking `word limit 120 for meta description`. Some time Magento is used `description field as long text area` thus meta description has been `cross the goggle setting`. That is not good for SEO health.

So Magento provides `meta_description field where you can set meta data from Site`.

Magento only uses `meta description for SEO purpose`. Where product description has been show on several area for user.